# Find/Validate element in XSD

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, xsd, xsd-validation

I want to validate or find if a element exist in XSD file.

My XSD schema looks as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- XSD -->
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://integration.cbre.com/schemas/gws/processinvoice/v1" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:simpleType name="Type_DATE">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:complexType name="Type_Document1">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="Comments" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Type_Document2">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Sender" type="Type_Document1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Receiver" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Email" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Type" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Remarks" type="Type_Document3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Type_Document3">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Phone" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Fax" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Email" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Comments" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Now in c# or vb.net i need to validate if specific field exist in XSD schema.

e.g. if I pass following parameters to a function it should return true

- ValidateColumn("Type_Document1 ","State")
- ValidateColumn("Document1","State")

//Should use like to match with Type_Document1 if we passed Document1

```
Function ValidateColumn(Type as string, Element as string) as boolean
End Function
```

But if pass following then it should return false as these elements does not exist.

- ValidateColumn("Type_Document2 ","Designation")
- ValidateColumn("Document2 ","Title")

Answer (score 0):

Here's some VB.NET code that can get you going:

```
Dim dataSet As Data.DataSet = New Data.DataSet

'add xsd with tables and columns into data table

dataSet.ReadXmlSchema(params.XsdPath)

'loop through each table and col
For Each dtable As Data.DataTable In DataSet.Tables
    For Each col As Data.DataColumn In dtable.Columns
        'could do a case statement here on document names which would be 
        'your table names
        'then do if col equals your element, true
    Next
Next
```

Comment: if I helped please mark as answer, if not tell me what other issues you are having and i can try to help more.Thanks

Comment: Tx for asking Mark. Got busy in other stuff. Hopefully will test it this evening or tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

I used `C# programming language` and `System.Xml.Linq` library for your qustion as follows:
I wrote `ValidateColumn` metod like that:

```
bool ValidateColumn(string rootTypeName, string fieldName)
{
    bool contains = false;
    var xDoc = XDocument.Load(yourXsdFilePath);
    foreach (var typeElement in xDoc.Root.Elements())
    {
        foreach (var field in typeElement.Elements().FirstOrDefault().Elements())
        {
            // checks if parent type element name equals give name, and child field element name equals given fieldName
            // and check this validation if your rootTypeName begins with 'Type_'

            int indexOfTypePrefix = typeElement.FirstAttribute.Value.IndexOf("Type_");
            if ((typeElement.FirstAttribute.Value == rootTypeName && field.FirstAttribute.Value == fieldName)
                    ||
                (indexOfTypePrefix == 0 && typeElement.FirstAttribute.Value.Substring(indexOfTypePrefix + 5) == rootTypeName
                    && field.FirstAttribute.Value == fieldName)
               )
            {
                contains = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (contains)
            break;
    }
    return contains;
}
```

and I tested it in a `console application`, its gives answers like you want.

```
Console.WriteLine("Function Validatetion for {0}, {1}: {2}", "Type_Document1", "State", ValidateColumn("Type_Document1", "State"));
// prints: Function Validatetion for Type_Document1, State: True
Console.WriteLine("Function Validatetion for {0}, {1}: {2}", "Document1", "State", ValidateColumn("Document1", "State"));
// prints: Function Validatetion for Document1, State: True
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Function Validatetion for {0}, {1}: {2}", "Type_Document2", "Designation", ValidateColumn("Type_Document2", "Designation"));
// prints: Function Validatetion for Type_Document2, Designation: False
Console.WriteLine("Function Validatetion for {0}, {1}: {2}", "Document2", "Title", ValidateColumn("Document2", "Title"));
// prints: Function Validatetion for Document2, Title: False
```

ps. I used `FirstAttribute` property for getting property name, so your name attribute have to be written first in your node for this code. And you can optimize this code.